# Nagios core installation problem

Tags: 14.04, server, apache2, network-monitoring, nagios3

i tried to configure nagios and every thing went fine and even installed apache2 web server. The final step of installation is generating a web link and access the dashboard using browser. But while accessing web browser the dashboard is not loading and a message "not found" displayed in the browser. What to do now?
This is the command for generating link:
ln -s /usr/share/apache2/ /var/www/html/apache2

Comment: nagios logs even generating and can be seen in nagios log file

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the command without the slash in the end? `ln -s /usr/share/apache2 /var/www/html/apache2`